# Is There A Way To Decorate a Previously Provided Service In Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, factory, inject

I'm trying to extend an Angular library, but my library would require specific settings for one of the services in order to work. I was hoping I could somehow use the decorator pattern (not a TypeScript decorator) to re-provide the service through a factory. This would involve having the previously declared service injected into the factory, and either modify the existing implementation or return an alternative version that uses the original one. It doesn't appear that my factory method is being called though.

```js
export function decoratedTranslateServiceFactory(tranlateService: TranslateService) {
  // either make changes to translateService or return an 
  // alternate version that uses the original one 
  // (i.e. new MyTranslateService(translateService))
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule],
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: TranslateService, 
      useFactory: decoratedTranslateServiceFactory,
      deps: [TranslateService] // <-- Same type as provided
    }
  ] 
})
export class MyTranslateModule {}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [TranslateModule, MyTranslateModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My hope is that the modified version of the TranslateService (from the factory provided by my module) would be the one provided to the rest of the application. I was hoping I can use this approach or a similar one to extend or wrap the existing service. Is this even possible?

Thanks for any advice.

Edit: Adding a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-decorate-provided-service).

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code, I think your factory is not being called because you have **not injected** the dependency anywhere in your code. It is **not enough**  to only import the module that contains that dependency.

However, if you function was called, you should be getting some cyclic dependency related errors.

Here's my attempt to this:

#### app.tokens.ts

```js
export class DecoratedService {
  static instance: DecoratedService;

  /* ... */

  constructor () { }

  /* ... */
}

export function decoratedServiceFactory () {
  console.warn('[DECORATING]');
  if (!DecoratedService.instance) {
    DecoratedService.instance = new DecoratedService();
  }

  const service = DecoratedService.instance;

  /* Decorate the service... */

  return service;
}
```

#### app.module.ts

```js
/* ... */
{
  provide: DecoratedService,
  useFactory: decoratedServiceFactory,
}
/* ... */
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/di-tips?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.tokens.ts).
(*scroll down to the last line*)